# geb jquery.mouseover() not working

Tags: selenium, geb

The [geb documentation](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/javascript.html) shows that it has built in jQuery support. Im interested in one particular method called mouseover. However when I try to use the mouseover function I get a warning saying, "Cannot resolve symbol 'mouseover'". This happens even when I'm using the code in their example. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure jQuery is installed on the browser. Geb will not install it.

Comment: Can you please share the code? It's extremely hard to help when you don't share the code and the exact error/stracktrace you're getting.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. In Geb Spock Groovy I am trying to `$("div#a").jquery.mouseover()` but Intillij throws syntax error `Cannot resolve symbol mouseover`. But the Geb Doc mentions the use of `jquery.mouseover`

Answer (score 1):

This might not directly answer your question. But if you are trying to mimic mouse over action in Geb, you could also use

```
  interact {
    moveToElement(element)
  }
```

http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#interact-closures